# Button in UpdatePanel triggers event, but the page doesn't update

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback, code-behind

Here's the markup:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="well well-large">
            <form class="navbar-form pull-left">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="test" runat="server" CssClass="input-small" />
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="btn" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panAlert" Visible="false">
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="divAlert" runat="server">
        <button id="Button1" runat="server" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
        You shouldn't see this message!
    </div>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panMarquee" Visible="true">
        <div id="Div1" runat="server" class="progress progress-success progress-striped">
            <div id="ProgressBar" runat="server" class="bar" style="width: 100%"></div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

When the btnUpload button is clicked, the server code is supposed to determine if the FileUpload control has a file. If it does, it will change the visibility of the Panel control to true. It works fine outside of the UpdatePanel.

Here's the server code:

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.SetMessage(Message.Success);
        try
        {
            if (this.test.HasFile)
            {
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(GetUB04Doc.FileName);
                //test.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
                this.SetMessage(Message.Success);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO: Do something with th exception
            this.SetMessage(Message.Fail);
        }
        finally
        {
            //this.GetUB04Doc.Dispose();
        }
    }
private enum Message { Success, Fail }
    private void SetMessage(Message msg)
    {
        if (msg == Message.Success)
        {
            this.divAlert.InnerText = "Well done! The document appears to have uploaded successfully. Please wait...";
            this.divAlert.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-success");
        }
        else
        {
            this.divAlert.InnerText = "Oh snap! Something broke. Please contact IT right away.";
            this.divAlert.Attributes.Add("class", "alert alert-error");
        }

        this.panAlert.Visible = true;
    }
```

I tried putting the Panel in the ContentTemplate section as well, but the results were the same.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I hate to tell you but `FileUpload` controls don't work properly in `UpdatePanels`! There are work arounds such as using `AsyncFileUpload` from MS Ajax Toolkit.

Comment: Why Update Panel and why not Json and Jquery to post data ?

Comment: @Belogix Thanks. I'll switch to the AJAX control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should surround the area which you are modifying from an async postback in another `UpdatePanel` with `UpdateMode` is set to `Conditional`. Then update the other manually from codebehind:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panAlertUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panAlert" Visible="false">
        <!-- ....
```

codebehind:

```
// ...
this.panAlert.Visible = true;
panAlertUpdatePanel.Update()
```

Side-note: As @Belogix has already commented, you should use an [`AsyncFileUpload`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) control in an `UpdatePanel` since a regular `FileUpload` control it's not supported with an asynchronous postback.

[**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Controls that Are Not Compatible with UpdatePanel Controls:

- ...
- `FileUpload` and `HtmlInputFile` controls when they are used to upload files as part of an **asynchronous postback**.
- ...

> To use a FileUpload or HtmlInputFile control inside an UpdatePanel
>   control, set the postback control that submits the file to be a
>   PostBackTrigger control for the panel. The FileUpload and
>   HtmlInputFile control can be used only in postback scenarios.

Comment: You should throw some light here also http://stackoverflow.com/q/16697601/2333922

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `PostBackTrigger` instead of `AsyncPostBackTrigger` like this. `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUpload" />`