# Response.redirect does not preserve HttpContext.Current.Items

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I was learning about the `HttpContext` and found out that

> HttpContext object will be constructed newly for every request given
>   to an ASP.Net application

Now, consider a case, when I have two pages. WebForm1 and Webform2. In Form1, I am writing the below mentioned code and redirects to form2.

```
HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("Key", "Value");
```

### **Query**

When I use Server.Transfer this key persist and this is not the case while using Response.Redirect

### **Confusion**

Wnenever a new request is generated, HttpCopntext object is created. Moreover, Session is preserved. Which is part of HttpContext.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

If Session can persist, why can't `HttpContext.Current.Items` in `Response.Redirect`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096544/application-vs-session-vs-cache

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirect generates a new `HttpContext` which is why the items in it are lost - the redirect effectively tells the browser the next URL to request, and when it does it loses the context of the previous request that triggered the redirect.

The session persists across requests (typically using a sessionID cookie to tie the user to values on the server), and is thus still available.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session` persist and `HttpContext.Cuttent.Items` not. Why ?

Comment: Because the first is design to persist across requests and the second is not.

Comment: I mean, Which things holds `Session` and does not hold Items ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you to look with [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) at `System.Web.dll`, in particular at property `HttpContext.Session` that uses in getter `HttpContext.Items["AspSession"]` and at method `SessionStateModule.InitStateStoreItem(...)` (called in that getter) wich calls `SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(...)`. You can see, that content of HttpSessionState collection is stored between requests in `SessionStateStoreProviderBase` implemented (*InProc*, *Sql*) object, more deeper in one word. Whereas `HttpContext.Items` hashtable is initialized at first get and dies between requests.